# How to clear (to remove) all the queued functions in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, queue

I would like to know how to clear (to remove) all the queued functions in jQuery? This is the code that I have:

```
var a = $('<div class="notification" style="bottom:'+ind+'px">Message envoyé '+i+'<span class="close">x</span></div>')
   .fadeIn(1000,"linear").delay(5000).fadeOut(3000,"linear");
```

I would like to remove the functions "fadeIn", "delay" and "fadeOut". I tried with dequeue() and with clearQueue() but it didn't work correctly. So how to do that?

Comment: HI, those are not queued functions, they are chained functions. You cannot clear it. You need to make a work around for it

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to achieve (and when)? As it stands, your question is very unclear.

Comment: @Steve: please have a look at this link: [link](http://jsbin.com/tawix/2/edit)..you will find all my code there. In fact I am trying to make notification pop-up bubbles like we find on Facebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've started an animation, you can stop it and clear any other queued animations by calling this on the objects that are animating:

```
$(yourobj).stop(true);
```

Or, in your case (since the jQuery object is in the variable `a`, it would be:

```
a.stop(true);
```

As you can see from the [jQuery doc for `.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), the first argument tells it to clear the queue of any other animations that are queued up to go.

---

Note, your code by itself isn't complete because you've created some DOM elements, but not added them to the page so they won't be visible until you do.  I'm assuming you have that code, but just didn't include it.

---

If what you're really trying to do is this:

1. Popup bubble that, when left on its own will fadeIn, stay on screen for a certain amount of time and then fade out
2. If, at anytime while the bubble is showing, the user mouses over it, you want to snap it to full opacity and stop any animations so it remains forever as long as the mouse is over it.
3. Then if the mouse is moved out of it, you want it to stay on screen for a short time, then fadeout.

   ```
           var a = $('<div class="notification" style="bottom:'+ind+'px">Message envoyé '+i+'<span class="close">x</span></div>')
             .fadeIn(1000,"linear").delay(5000)
             .fadeOut(3000, "linear", function() {
                 $(this).remove();
             })
             .mouseover(function() {
                 $(this).stop(true).css("opacity", 1);
             }).mouseleave(function() {
                 $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(3000, "linear", function() {
                     $(this).remove();
                 });
             });
           $('body').append(a);
   ```

You can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/ziwexifo/1/edit

In your jsBin code, I honestly have no idea what you're trying to do with the `.promise().done()` code because I find the variable names non-descriptive so they don't help me know what you're trying to do and there are no comments.  If you're going to use `.stop()` to prematurely cancel the animation sequence, you will probably have to do something different than using the `.promise().done()` for all clean up work.  I've used the animation completion functions in my code.

Comment: Well, I tried with stop() but it still doesn't work correctly. By the way, to understand what I am trying to do, please have a look at this link: link..you will find all my code there. In fact I am trying to make notification pop-up bubbles like we find exactly on Facebook.

Comment: @NadimAkram - look at the rest of your code for what purpose?  Does this answer your question for how to clear those animations?  You need to be very clear about what you're asking for help with and I thought I'd already answered your question.

Comment: to understand what I am trying to do, please have a look at this link: [link](http://jsbin.com/tawix/2/edit). There you can find my complete code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NadimAkram - What exactly doesn't work correctly when you tried `.stop(true)`.  We can't guess what your problem is or what you need help with.  The link to your code doesn't help me because I don't know what I'm supposed to do on that page or what you think isn't working.  Please remember, we don't know your code, don't know what you expect it to do and don't know how to reproduce your specific issue unless you describe each of these things for us and ask a very specific question.

Comment: @NadimAkram - also, why are you using variable names `a`, `b`, `c`, etc...?  Variables should be given meaningful names like `counter` or `position` or `topValue`.  Your code is extremely hard to follow with meaningless variable names.

Comment: what I would like to do is when I mouseover the notification pop-up bubble, there will be no fadeout and the opacity of the bubble becomes equal to 1.0 (like what you can notice on Facebook), and when I mouseout the bubble there will be a delay then a fadeout. please, can you have a look at this line:
var a = $('<div class="notification" style="bottom:'+ind+'px">Message envoyé '+i+'<span class="close">x</span></div>').fadeIn(1000,"linear").delay(5000).fadeOut(3000,"linear").mouseover(function(){$(this).stop(true);}).mouseleave(function(){});

Comment: @NadimAkram - OK, finally you're describing what you actually want to happen.  I'll add an idea for a solution to my answer now.  FYI, please don't put multi-line pieces of code into comments as they are illegible.  If you want to share that type of code, then use the edit button to add it to the end of your question and post a comment that refers to the code you added.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer, I tried your code and it worked correctly, I really appreciate your help. Here is my new code:
[link](http://jsbin.com/tawix/3/edit).. By the way, I changed the code which exists inside the body of the .promise().done() function. In fact I wanted to indicate what should happen after the completion of the bubble animation by using .promise().done(). Anyway, thanks again for your help, I will mark your answer as the best one :)

Answer (score 1):

### Long Answer (For Deep understarting)

**IMPORTANT !** this answer is Long. and not meant to replaced the [best Short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24370360/1667129)
at all. But rather as understanding it more by playing with the demo.

So, First of...

I am founding the **Best Demonstration in this following [jQuery Site link: jQuery.finish()](https://api.jquery.com/finish/)**

So, please appreciate your time if your just need to finish up your project ASAP.
and of course you can came back anytime to it, as i also just made for my self. which is very good (Future) reference too.

It's show a very good Demo example in all of the scenarios that you could possible can across by. (to my humble opinion anyway)

Also, This [jQuery .clearQueue link](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) can really clear things up way better as "All of" or "Most of" those functions API are related in one way or another! (NOT 100% Accurate, but bare in mind.) so, don't get mislead by me (don't have yet experience with those all)

> When the .clearQueue() method is called, all functions on the queue that have not been executed are removed from the queue. When used without an argument, .clearQueue() removes the remaining functions from fx, the standard effects queue. In this way it is similar to .stop(true). However, while the .stop() method is meant to be used only with animations, .clearQueue() can also be used to remove any function that has been added to a generic jQuery queue with the .queue() method.

**On a personal note:**
I was just looking for a good Scroller (yes, the old Marquee) and end up running it with no plugins (not at first, didn't found good one. and only it's very easy with jQuery) but only with jQuery.animate() function which did the trick for me. (Good Job jQuery Community!!)

the problem that i run into is, after using setTimeout and function that call it self so the animate will repeat infinity, i ended up running multiple animation at once (after a while) and needed to reset it all.
so clearTimeout (for the setTimeout) and .stop(true) for the .animate() really helped me!
afterward i could restart it as many times as i wanted too and now i know, there isn't animate still on the air!